# Custom field remains readonly when invoice closed

Tags: acumatica

so I'm trying to add a small bool field to the SOInvoiceEntry graph, so it can be exposed to the API. It needs to remain editable even after the document has been closed and released. I've set up the DAC field as:

```
public class ARRegisterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister>
{
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Has been integrated", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, Enabled = true)]
    public virtual bool? UsrIsIntegrated { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrIsIntegrated : IBqlField { }
}
```

And added RowSelected events which should, in theory, be setting the field to enabled:

```
public class SOInvoiceEntry_Extensions : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public void SOInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseMethod)
    {
        baseMethod?.Invoke(sender, e);
        if (e.Row == null) return;

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<ARRegisterExt.usrIsIntegrated>(sender, e.Row, true);
    }
}
```

However the field remains readonly on closed invoices. I've tested this on the ARInvoiceEntry graph, and exposed that to the api, and it works fine. I've been testing different methods of setting the field as enabled, but no luck so far.

Any help would be awesome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by an automation step on the SOInvoiceEntry screen setting the ARInvoice table as disabled, which was overriding the logic I was adding.